# Delorem XMap Hex/Binary to Lat Long

Tags: hex, coordinates, decode

I have a data dump from a database used by XMap.

It looks like XMap stores the Lat/Lng as a Hex value. Can anyone help me decode these?

I was also able to use Xmap to upload some of my own data and see how it converted that to Hex. I am just unable to do a bulk export with the version of Xmap that I have.

Long: -100.00  Lat :35.00       0000004E 0000806E

-101.00 35.00        0000804D 0000806E

-101.1  35.1  3333734D 3333736E
-101.2  35.2  6666664D 6666666E

---

Lat          Lon               Hex
35.21285737 -98.44795716       0x57A9C64E17C1646E
35.21305335 -98.44786274       0x6FACC64EABBA646E
35.94602108 -96.74434793    0x35B9A04FC8E8066E
34.89283431 -99.037117  0xC03F7B4E9BB78D6E
34.89300668 -99.03754044    0xE0317B4EF5B18D6E
34.41109633 -100.2820795    0xD2E4DB4D3261CB6E
33.97470069 -101.2196311    0x21E3634D023D036F
34.0079211  -101.1440331    0x53906D4D71FCFE6E
32.76227534 -104.2691193    0x808DDD4BC36D9E6F
32.77947819 -104.204128 0x22DFE54B0F3A9C6F
32.77947819 -104.204128 0x22DFE54B0F3A9C6F
32.64307308 -104.5322441    0x6DDFBB4BC8AFAD6F
32.64290345 -104.531814 0x85EDBB4B57B5AD6F
32.47907078 -104.5652282    0x9AA6B74BCFADC26F
32.47907078 -104.5652282    0x9AA6B74BCFADC26F
32.22682178 -101.3943434    0x28864D4D81F7E26F
32.07237184 -101.8558813    0x7B72124D85BCF66F
31.89574015 -102.4611448    0x35F9C44C63580D70
31.8808713  -102.4563805    0x5395C54C9C3F0F70
31.18487537 -101.1440152    0xE9906D4D01566870
31.28633738 -100.4128259    0x8528CB4D4C595B70
31.0369339  -100.5050048    0x015CBF4DC0457B70
30.83263898 -100.6261411    0x9CDAAF4D166C9570

Comment: are you sure the hex code is derived from the lat lon info?

Comment: It looked highly likely to me. I did not post all the data here but from some other data points it seemed like the second half of the HEX had some type of correlation with Lat.

Comment: the only thing that stands out at first glance in this sample is that identical Lat Lon points get identical hex codes, but I see no immediate similarity between close coordinates and their codes. For all I know the code could be some irreversible hash of the coordinates - then again, I was never much into deciphering codes or reverse engineering...

Answer (score 1):

So this exact problem just came up at work a last night, and I spent a few hours decoding and converting the information.

It appears that the lat and long are stored in 32-bit Little-endian chunks ([read more about endianness here (wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness))

From your example `35.21285737 -98.44795716` `0x57A9C64E17C1646E` converts as follows:

```
Split to 32 bit sections -->  0x57A9C64E (lng)   0x17C1646E (lat)

Adjust for endianness
    LAT: 17 C1 64 6E  => Swap Bytes =>  6E 64 C1 17  ==> 1852096791 (base 10)
    LNG: 57 A9 C6 4E  => Swap Bytes =>  4E C6 A9 57  ==> 1321642327 (base 10)
```

from that information, I then used a linear regression to figure out a conversion equation (http://arachnoid.com/polysolve/.  Originally, I tried using Excel's regression tools, but it didn't provide nearly enough accuracy).  It ended up working out much nicer than I originally thought.  However, it seems like there should be a `sign` bit within the data, but I didn't figure out how to retrieve it, so there are two separate equations for whether it is lat or long.

```
LAT = 256 + raw / -2^23
LNG = -256 + raw / 2^23
```

If we go ahead and run our test data through the equations we receive:

```
Lat: 35.212857365
Lng: -98.447957158
```

If i get more time in the future, I may try to figure out a more efficient method for converting (taking the sign bit into account) but for now this method worked well enough for me.

Now that this data if figured out, one could expand it to be able to convert the raw data for other more complex geometry types (such as lines).  I haven't had a chance to finish working out all the details for RAW data that's used with lines.  However, what I did look at it seems that it includes a header that contains some additional information, such as how many Lat/Long Points are in the data.  Other than that, it looked about as straightforward as the single points.

-- Edit --

Revisited this today and after much digging found a better formula for conversion from GPSBable [source code](https://github.com/gpsbabel/gpsbabel/blob/master/an1.cc#L164).

```
COORD = (0x80000000 - raw) / 0x800000
```

We can also do the inverse and convert from a COORD back to the raw data

```
RAW = 0x80000000 - (coord * 0x800000)
```

I also looked into the sign bit and as far as I can tell, sign bits are not stored in the data, so you have to be aware of that.  I also have code that implements Point, Line, and Polygon decoding in PHP if anybody needs it.